# Yii, form using 2 models -> skip the validation on one

Tags: forms, yii, validation

I have one form using to different models. I want to be able to create a new Person and eventually a new User, to give this person an account. A person doens't need to have a User related (could be just a person used for statistics or something like that). I have a checkbox in my form "Click if you want create a user" and I show the user part of the form if it's checked.

Then in the controller I can, with the checkbox value, know if I need call performAjax() for both Person and User or only Person.

But my problem is about the client validation. If I try to submit the form without the User required field, for example, the submition will abort and i'll get some errors like "This field is requiered".

So, my question is how could I skip the validation of my user model if its fields are empty (checkebox unchecked, we don't want to create a user).

Any help are welcom :)

Sorry for my bad English.

Have a good day :)

Michaël S.

Comment: are you using jquery for client side validation?

Comment: @Michaël : You are doing validation using jQuery OR Using Model > Rules? Let us know. It is possible in both places using conditions.

Comment: Hello, I'm using the model->rule() method.

Answer (score 1):

When saving the model, set the first parameter on false to skip validation:

[$model->save(false)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail)